# Model relation between input and ouput

Tags: windows-7, data-visualization, modeling

I'm working on a piece of software that has a large amount of input parameters and output parameters. It is sometimes difficult to know how changes made to one input affects different output parameters.

I'm looking for a tool that could help me visualize/model how the system works. Does anyone know of any tools to accomplish this?

Thanks!